# To add optionsetvalue in MS CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-2013

I have to write a code which will add a new optionsetvalue in Plugin in MS CRM.

```
entity.Attributes.Add("test_entity", new OptionSetValue(1));
```

I have tried implementing this code but it doesn't do the work. Do suggest the code.

Comment: Define "doesn't work".  How are you verifying it?  How are you verifying the plugin is executing?  What event is the plugin registered for?

Comment: Are you trying to add a new value or are you trying to add a new option in the option set itself? Also what you did is working if in the plugin you are using a field that is not in the list of the attributes already. If that is the case Daryl solution will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have the correct syntax for updating or setting the OptionSetValue attribute of an entity.  You could do the same with a little less code:

```cs
entity["test_entity"] = new OptionSetValue(1);
```

So your issue is probably with the entity and the type of plugin you're executing.  Is `entity` the target of a plugin registered for the Create or Update of the Entity?  Then this should be all you have to do.  If the entity is some other value you've searched for, or will be creating, than you have to actually use the `IOrganizationService` to update/create the entity.

```cs
entity["test_entity"] = new OptionSetValue(1);
service.Update(entity);
```